# MATLAB structed data query: table vs database

Tags: matlab

I have a SQLigt db. It contains a few tables. By outer join, we have a larger table with columns.

```
c1 c2 c3 c4 c5
.. .. .. .. ..
.. .. .. .. ..
```

The typical operations are find a slice from the table in terms of some constraints, for example, c1 > 10 & c2 < 23.

I was wondering what is a better way to query structured data in MATLAB.

MATLAB has a table data type:

```
http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/tables.html
```

It supports intuitive boolean-indexing:

```
http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/access-data-in-a-table.html
```

and `join`/`union`/`diff` operations as normal data base. I notice a table can be created by either work-space variables or text files. In either case, I guess it has to load all data into memory. How about its performance? Is it salable when data is large.

MATLAB also has a data base interface:

```
http://www.mathworks.com/help/database/ug/database.html?searchHighlight=database
```

Will it be better in terms of performance? However it does not have a friendly query syntax like boolean-indexing.

In my case, the table is of size 1G on average, but could be of size 200G at worst case.

What is the best way to present and query structured data in MATLAB?

Comment: Maybe you could add more information on your target application. E.g. ammount of data (rows, cloumns). Typical operations and search queries you require on your data.

Comment: @BerndGit I updated my question with more background.

Answer (score 0):

Your search queries look like rather standard SQL operations. You could use the Matlab  [SQLite conection](http://de.mathworks.com/help/database/ug/sqlite.html) and use [fetch](http://de.mathworks.com/help/database/ug/fetch.html) to load only the data you need.

Comment: The table boolean-indexing seems designed for getting a sliced table with a more friendly syntax. What is the use case of table?

Comment: I'm not sure about matlab tables. But something like `curs = exec(conn,'select * from myTable Where c1 > 10 and c2 < 23');
slicedData = fetch(curs)` should give you what you want (w/o loading 200 Gb into memory).

Comment: The sqlite command is not available to me. Is the database toolbox installed by default?

Comment: It is an optional package with sepatate pricing: http://de.mathworks.com/pricing-licensing/index.html?intendeduse=comm&prodcode=DB

Comment: Maybe a workaround to safe licening cost if you are fit in Java: You need only few commands to access your database and these would all be availble in Java JDBC. Matlab also allows import of Java classes. So you could write a wrapper of these functions in Java and import it in Matlab. (Just an idea, not sure how much effort, since I havn't worked with Java import in Matlab myself. .. So here I cannot give you futher support)